# Unity3D sphere rotation and always keeping rotation direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a sphere gameobject with 5 cubes placed on different points on the surface of the sphere. When a key is pressed, i would like the sphere to spin for a few seconds and then slowly stops on the first cube point on the cube and always keeping the same direction in rotation. The issue i am facing now is that, Quaternion.Slerp always takes the shortest path to the next cube which means sometimes the rotation direction is changed. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle the rotation as a [Vector3 of Euler angles](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html).

This way you can [Linearly Interpolate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) the angles to the correct value. And you can use coterminal angles so that you're always interpolating to a higher value ( so no backwards rotations would occur ). After every rotational step you might want to normalize the angles to the 0, 360 range with this approach though.

Example Code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rotation : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform firstPosition;
    public Transform secondPosition;
    public float rotationDuration = 3;


    void Start () {
        transform.rotation = firstPosition.rotation;
        StartCoroutine(Rotate());
    }

    IEnumerator Rotate() {
        var deltaTime = 0.0f;
        var distance = firstPosition.rotation.eulerAngles - secondPosition.rotation.eulerAngles;


        while(deltaTime < rotationDuration) {
            var rotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            rotation = firstPosition.rotation.eulerAngles + deltaTime/rotationDuration*distance;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);
            deltaTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.rotation = secondPosition.rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more?